# A,B not empty and bounded above. Prove that $\sup(A + B)$ = $\sup(A)$ + $\sup(B)$.

Tags: real-analysis

The problem states that two sets A, B are nonempty and bounded above. Define $A + B$ as the set of all elements $a + b$ where $a \in A, b \in B$. Prove that $\sup(A + B)$ = $\sup(A)$ + $\sup(B)$.

Part c asks to prove this statement directly from the results of parts a and b. Part d requires using Lemma 1.3.8 to prove the same fact:

Assume $s \in R$ is an upper bound for a set $A \subseteq R$. Then $s =$ sup$A$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$, some element $a \in A$ exists such that $s - \epsilon < a$.

I'm just curious as to how to use Lemma 1.3.8? It's in the format "p iff q" so do I need to focus on the "q" statement? Take an $\epsilon$ value at random and show that some element $a+b$ exists where $\sup(A) + \sup(B) - \epsilon < a + b$?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, and here's a hint: One way to achieve $\sup A + \sup B -\epsilon <a+b$ is to first show $\sup A-\epsilon/2<a$ and $\sup B-\epsilon/2<b$.

But in order to apply the lemma to $A+B$, you also need to show that $\sup A + \sup B$ is an upper bound for $A+B$. (Is this fact easy or hard to prove?)